# What to do when no base class exists to a certain common interface in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, class, interface, actionlistener

What is the base class or interface for the jTextField, jComboBox, etc... which allows you to use the 'addActionListener' method to them?

So if there is no interface like that, What could I do to make a Map of `JComponents` that allows the `addActionListener` method

Comment: Are you aware of how [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) works?

Comment: It's specified in the Oracle javadocs.

Comment: Though they both dont seem to offer a common base class containging the action listener support methods. You're probably searching something like this [interface](https://github.com/ahanin/opencv-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/tk/year/opencv/demo/ui/ActionListenerSupport.java)

Comment: Is there a reason to recently remove the accept on my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry it was a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [interface](https://github.com/ahanin/opencv-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/tk/year/opencv/demo/ui/ActionListenerSupport.java) and create wrappers for each component type you need. `JTextFieldSupportWrapper` and `JComboboxSupportWrapper` both taking an instance of the wrapped object type and and delegating to the `addActionListener` methods.

```
abstract class ActionListenerSupportWrapper<T extends JComponent> 
    implements ActionListenerSupport
{
    protected final T comp;
    protected ActionListenerSupportWrapper(T comp) {
        this.comp = comp;
    }
 }

// for each supported component type
class JTextFieldSupportWrapper extends ActionListenerSupportWrapper<JTextField> {
    void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        comp.addActionListener(l);
    }
}
```

Now you could declare a map using the interface `ActionListenerSupport` and add wrapped instances into that map i'll take a list for now.

```
List<ActionListenerSupport> l = // init
JTextField tf = // lookup
l.add(new JTextFieldSupportWrapper(tf));
```

hope this helps

I think this post can be improved with reflection not having to create the subtypes on your own. But may be you loose some type safety at compile time.